# UPPER_CASE naming style in __init__.py in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, pylint

I am wondering what the proper convention is for the init file in Python Flask.
Is there a way to format an init file in such a way in Flask that all the variables are not interpreted as constants? Currently my Pylint is saying that all the variables such as 'app' need to be renamed to be compliant with the UPPER_CASE naming style.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, SMTPHandler
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
mail = Mail(app)

from app import routes, models, errors

if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
        auth = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
            auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
        secure = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
            secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
            fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
            toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Microblog Failure',
            credentials=auth, secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/microblog.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                       backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Microblog startup')
```

Comment: pylint requires all variables in the outermost scopes to be constants. Could you try putting your main code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Answer (score 2):

As per pylint's definition, any variable at the module level is a constant.
as `@adrianp` suggested in the comment move the entire code into a 
method (say `run_stuff`) and invoke it by

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_stuff()
```